# CentOS 6.5 Xen Virtual Machine Issue 'this function is not supported by the connection driver'

Tags: centos, virtualization, xen, centos6

I am trying to segment my system into a number of virtual machines but just cant seem to get this to work. I think I am close but not quite there. I have install xen, virsh, xl etc and I am using virsh to try and create a new VM.

```
virt-install --virt-type xen --name centos6 --ram 2048 --vcpus=4 -f /dev/vg0/centosvirtfs --location http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/ --os-type linux --accelerate --nographics --network=bridge:br0
```

As you can see I am trying to create a new container called centos6 with 2048 MB of RAM and 4 VCPUs. It begins downloading the necessary resources from the location directive but then at the point of creating the domain I get the following error -

```
[root@server install]# virt-install --virt-type xen --name centos6 --ram 2048 --vcpus=4 -f /dev/vg0/centos6 --location http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/ --os-type linux --accelerate --nographics --network=bridge:br0

Starting install...
Retrieving file .treeinfo...                             |  728 B     00:00 ... 
Retrieving file vmlinuz...                               | 7.9 MB     00:11 ... 
Retrieving file initrd.img...                            |  64 MB     00:06 ... 
Creating domain...                                       |    0 B     00:00     
Connected to domain centos6
Escape character is ^]

error: this function is not supported by the connection driver: virDomainOpenConsole
Domain installation still in progress. You can reconnect to 
the console to complete the installation process.

[root@server install]# virsh console centos6
Connected to domain centos6
Escape character is ^]
error: this function is not supported by the connection driver: virDomainOpenConsole
```

So as you can see it almost creates the container and when I try and console into it I am getting the virDomainOpenConsole error. Any ideas?

Chris.